# Object of ArrayLists, how to add/remove them from the object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
public class MapData {

    ArrayList<String> Redsp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Bluesp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Playersp = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MapData(ArrayList<String> redsp, ArrayList<String> bluesp, ArrayList<String> playersp) {
        Redsp = redsp;
        Bluesp = bluesp;
        Playersp = playersp;
    } 
}
```

How do I make a object of MapData, and add/remove items to/from the object?
I would like to add like 6 items to `bluesp` and `redsp`, and 20 to `playersp`.

```
MapData TEST = new MapData(null,null,null);
TEST.??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create some more methods to MapData

For example to add to Bluesp

```
public void addToBlueSp(String string) {
    Bluesp.add(string);
}
```

Also I would use camelCase as this is the standard thing to do in Java.

I would probably recommend creating the ArrayLists inside the ctor too as there is little point passing them into an object and then using that object to add/remove items from them. If you have the ArrayList you could add them outside of this object. But that is a design thing...

Comment: I find this the easiest way for me, But how do I loop thru Bluesp? and how do get get(index int)?

Comment: @user1621988 If you want to apply all the operations of `ArrayList` it would be easier for you just to add getter methods for the `ArrayList`s and then do your operations on them...

Comment: u mean like: public String getBluesp(int index) { // Bluesp.get(index) ?

Comment: @user1621988 Of course, you can add all those methods to `MapData`, but just returning the contained arraylist would be much easier in your case (though not what I recommend in general). i.e. add a getter for each arraylist: `public ArrayList<String> getBluesp()` and afterwards use `get` or iterate over the list or whatever you want.

Comment: public void addRedsp(String loc) {
 Redsp.add(loc);
}
TEST.addRedsp("Test");

Gives me a NPE

Comment: @user1621988 Of course it does. `Redsp` is `null`. See my answer to avoid that...

Comment: Thanks, TEST.Bluesp.get(index) seems to work as well now. but I will stick to the methode inside MapData.

Answer (score 0):

Use `add()` and `remove()` methods

**-** You can opt for creating the **adding and removing** `methods` Or make all the `ArrayList` as **static**

**Eg:**

```
public void addToRedSp(String string) {

    Redsp.add(string);

} 


public void remToRedSp(String string) {

    Redsp.remove(string);

} 

MapData TEST = new MapData(null,null,null);

    // To add

    test.addToRedSp("Vivek");

    // To remove

    test.remToRedSp(0);   // or  MapData.Redsp.remove("Vivek");
```

**-** `ArrayList` as **static**

```
public static ArrayList<String> Redsp = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> Bluesp = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> Playersp = new ArrayList<String>();



MapData TEST = new MapData(null,null,null);

// To add

MapData.Redsp.add("Vivek");

// To remove

MapData.Redsp.remove(0);   // or  MapData.Redsp.remove("Vivek");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to provide getters for the three collections and then manipulate them the ordinary way. Such manipulations will take effect on the member fields:

```
public class MapData {

    ArrayList<String> Redsp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Bluesp = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Playersp = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MapData(ArrayList<String> redsp, ArrayList<String> bluesp, ArrayList<String> playersp) {
        Redsp = redsp;
        Bluesp = bluesp;
        Playersp = playersp;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getRedsp(); 
}
```

And then you do:

```
MapData TEST = new MapData(null,null,null);
TEST.getRedsp().add("Text1");
TEST.getRedsp().add("Text2");
```

and so on.

However, take care: you construct not with empty lists, but with null and my code will trigger NPE. Consider setting the default values to empty lists.

Comment: This breaks the law of dementer a bit though

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon it is just a matter of compromise - yes it makes your code more tightly coupled, but on the other hand you do not need to implement all container access methods for each member container.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add getter and setter methods for the `List`s to `MapData` and add new elements like this:

```
TEST.getRedsp().add("hello");
```

with

```
public ArrayList<String> getRedsp()
{
    if(Redsp == null)
        Redsp = new ArrayList<String>();

    return Redsp;
}
```

or you can introduce an add method for each list to `MapData`:

```
TEST.addToRedsp("hello");
```

with

```
public boolean addToRedsp(String value)
{
    if(Redsp == null)
        Redsp = new ArrayList<String>();

    return Redsp.add(value)
}
```

Proceed similarly for the delete case.

By the way: Have a look at [variable naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).